# My infix makes 500 minus 9

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

I'm new, and this is my very first affix riddle!  Thanks for letting me join in.

> My prefix survives above the tree line without you.
>
> My infix makes 500 minus 9.
>
> My suffix is always a little amped up, or maybe down?

What process am I?

Hint:

> 500 is not a number

Comment: I fear I was overly vague, so I edited the question to clarify that the answer is a process, and added a hint.  Chalk it up to a noob mistake.

Comment: rot13(Va Rkpry, VFAHZORE(500) ergheaf GEHR.  Bar bs lbh vf pbashfrq! ;))

Comment: rot13(Nf n sryybj rkpry areq, V srry yvxr V jnyxrq evtug vagb gung bar!  Jryy cynlrq.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My prefix survives above the tree line without you

> Init : Inuit - u, as they live at a latitude higher than trees can grow.

My infix makes 500 minus 9

> iat : Fiat  - F, as the 500 is the city car and F is atomic symbol number 9.

My suffix is always a little amped up, or maybe down?

> ion : the charged particle which may be positive or negative.

Welcome to Puzzling and you will have passed the

> initiation!

Comment: NICE! That's actually really clever. I was hung up on ALPINE for the first and couldn't think past that. +1 for you!

Comment: That was fun for me.  Did I make it too easy, though?  I imagine there's a razor's edge between too vague and too easy.

Comment: It was tough! I thought of the middle first but was stuck on the prefix with a high altitude chiru or for the suffix a try (rugby touchdown) and thought you might be finding your feet in podiatry or  as a chiropractor  -  the intro on joining was a good help:)

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be a

> Rixdaler which is an alternate spelling of Ruksdaalder, a Dutch 2 1/2 guilder piece

My prefix survives above the tree line without you

> Rix is a dialect variant of Rush, specifically the meaning of: any of various plants especially of the genera Juncus and Scirpus.  *Juncus trifidus* (Highland rush) as an example is found in boreal and alpine cliffs, ridges and plateaus above treeline.

My infix makes 500 minus 9

> IXD is one way to write 491 in Roman numerals, though CDXCI is the proper way.

My suffix is always a little amped up, or maybe down?

> Daler - Daler Mehndi is an Indian performer/singer.  In such a role he is amped up?  Currently he's facing criminal charges for human trafficking, thus amped down?

Additional note:

> As @z100 points out, there is also a Rix-dollar (hyphenated per Merriam-Webster).  This would make the suffix "dollar" which is up or down with regard to AMP (a crypto currency)?  Though I don't particularly feel strongly that "daler" is what was intended, I don't feel any better about this version mainly because of the hyphen.  Now if the infix clue was 9 minus 500, then ix - d would make much more sense to me!

Comment: Rixdollar also possible with Dollar as a suffix, which is from the enigmatic point of wiev not so good as the root  of an entire word. Try https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat  with .ixd.

Comment: Nope, but I learned something new there. 0 of 3.